# Compiling boost::math's Performance Test Application

Tags: c++, boost, build

Has anyone successfully compiled the performance test application for boost::math library?
link: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/perf/perf_test_app.html

I tried compiling by running b2 in the directory and there were lots of errors (over 222000 lines).

First few lines of errors:

```
../test/erf_data.ipp:6:74: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
In file included from ../../../boost/math/tools/rational.hpp:13:0,
                 from ../../../boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp:18,
                 from ../../../boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:35,
                 from test_erf.cpp:9:
../../../boost/array.hpp:60:11: error: provided for ‘template<class T, long unsigned int N> class boost::array’
In file included from test_erf.cpp:13:0:
../test/erf_data.ipp:6:80: error: template argument 1 is invalid
../test/erf_data.ipp:6:91: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
../test/erf_data.ipp:7:38: error: ‘SC_’ was not declared in this scope
../test/erf_data.ipp:7:88: error: ‘SC_’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from test_erf.cpp:13:0:
../test/erf_data.ipp:7:136: error: ‘SC_’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: You could at least provide the errors..

Comment: @StackUnderflow But it is over 200000 lines.

Comment: What about providing the first 10-20 lines of errors?

Comment: @Deqing Done. Anyone intending to answer this will need to try compiling it. The error messages I have are probably not useful at all.

Comment: If I answered 'probably' I should get the bounty, but I'll be down voted... (>_<)

Comment: @toor if you can compile and run the application, I will give you the bounty

Comment: I have had boost errors like this before, are you compiling with Cmake, because mine occurred when i wasn't linking the boost stuff in the correct order.

Comment: @Ben I am compiling with b2. didnt know of the cmake alternative, is that the recommended compilation method? you can try compiling it and let me know the results.

Comment: So far i got it to compile, but i have a linker error, i think i almost have it figured out.

Comment: Do you know what the boost dependencies for this library are?

Comment: @Ben What did you use to compile? b2 should be able to find the boost dependencies automatically, right?

Comment: No i am using cmake, you need to link the libraries independently and manually. Therefore the code does compile so i don't get the errors but it cant link to the correct libraries. Do you know what boost libraries the program uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it to compile and link properly but it was not with b2. I know the OP asked for b2 but im not familiar with it so i am providing an alternative. This solution assumes you have Cmake installed. (easy to do, just ask dr google.)

If you go to the math tests location:

```
~/pathToBoost/libs/math/performance
```

and you add a file called:

```
CMakeLists.txt
```

with the following Contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS  REQUIRED)
include_directories(${DEPENDENCY_DIR}/libboost/lib)

add_executable(main main.cpp test_reference.cpp)
target_link_libraries (main ${Boost_LIBRARIES} boost_regex)
```

Then you make a folder called build:

```
mkdir build
```

And build it.

```
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Doing this got me successful compilation and building. I get a program called main out of it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i can get cmake .. to run, but what is `build`? which package does it come from?

Comment: build is part of the c++ compiler, what operating system are you developing on? linux? So typing build doesn't work? Maybe that is why your original code isn't working, maybe you don't have a compiler?

Comment: Ok, so in the build file, after you run "cmake .." inside build, are some files created including a MakeFile?

Comment: @ggg OH OH OH, i am very sorry, that should be make not build, dam i am an idiot, changing the answer now.

Comment: got this `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex`

Comment: did you run sudo apt-get install libboost1.46-all-dev ?

Comment: works after i installed boost. can i make it link to my own compiled boost? `main --all` does not do any test. Something is not right with the compilation, reading the *.cpp files you will notice that gsl and Rmath standalone libraries are required (this is a comparison test of boost::math against those libraries), but the compilation was successful without the libraries.

Comment: @ggg yep, well sorry if its not what you wanted. I'm not super experienced with boost so I'm not sure of another way to do it.

Comment: Thanks anyway. will give you the bounty if no one can give a better answer before the bounty ends.